# Common iOS Memory Leak Issue Due to Custom Segues. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, storyboard, segue

I have seen variations of the following code all over StackOverflow:

```
import UIKit

class segueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        let src = self.source.view as UIView!
        let dst = self.destination.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        dst?.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: screenWidth,
height: screenHeight)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view
above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(dst!, aboveSubview: src!)

        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            src?.frame = (src?.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0))!
            dst?.frame = (dst?.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0))!

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in

            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil) {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

At first, the code operates as a nice way of transitioning from one view to another. But with continued use, most of the problems that have been listed on this website as a result from it relate to memory. Every time the segue is used, the destination view is initialized and the source view remains in memory. With continued use, the memory use continues to grow and grow.

A simple dismissal of the source view did not function for me, the screen just went black.

My question is, how can we fix this problem?

Comment: The problem isn't in this code. The problem is how you are managing your view controller stack; if you continually present new view controllers then the previous view controllers are just sitting there in memory. You need to think about how navigation works in your app. Can you use unwind segues to go back to a previous instance of a view controller?  Can you use a navigation or tab bar controller to manage view controllers?

Comment: In the case of my app, I cannot use a navigation or tab bar controller. You are correct in the sense that I continuously present new view controllers. Now that has me thinking an unwind segue may work, but I don’t know what it is exactly and I have specific animations I use for each type of segue. I’d want to stay consistent with those animations.

Comment: If you search you will find details on unwind segues, but essentially they let you unwind back to a previous view controller in your stack regardless of how many intermediate view controllers have been pushed. You can create the appropriate unwind transition if you want a specific effect.

Comment: Thanks for the information, i’ll do some research on unwinds. Essentially then the code itself doesn’t cause the problem, to my understanding.

Comment: That is right; It just handles the transition.